# Angular dynamic class using variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an `enum` that map a given keyword to a CSS class.

```js
enum Colors {
 WHT = 'color--white'
}
```

and inside the component I created a new property with that value `colors = Colors`
and I'm using it as it follows

```html
 <p [ngClass]="[colors['WHT']]">My paragraph</p>
```

In this scenario it works as expected.

The problem is when I try to add a condition to this class binding.

```html
 <p [ngClass]="{ [colors['WHT']]: false }> My paragraph </p>"
```

The official [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) doesn't provide any information about this use case, but it doesn't provide an example for `<p [ngClass]="[componentColors['WHT']]"> My paragraph</p>` either and this approach works fine.

**Update:**
The `false` condition is just demo purposes, in the real scenario it will use a variable.

Comment: Can you try to remove [] around colors['WHT'] like that:  <p [ngClass]="{ colors['WHT']: false }> My paragraph </p>  ? Is it working ?

Comment: Hi, I've tried and is not working.

Comment: why `[ngClass]="[colors['WHT']]"` works? What is this outer array index syntax on the right supposed to do?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea why this does not throw an error in the template, but having outer [] is redundant here.

Answer (score 0):

Create proper json object in the component layer, then bind it

component:

```
  colors=Colors;
  yourStyles={ 
    'foo':false,
    'bar':true,
    [this.colors['WHT']]: true, 
  }
```

template:

```
<p [ngClass]="yourStyles">My paragraph</p>
```

result:

```
<p _ngcontent-wma-c40="" class="bar color--white" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">My paragraph</p>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-roatih?file=src/app/app.component.html

obviously `yourStyles` has to reflect requested conitions to enable/disable given class.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in the following:

```html
<p [ngClass]="true ? colors['WHT']:''"> My Paragraph </p>
```

Where `true` is the condition (property).